# Twillio AutoPilot how to end session using the wizard

Tags: twilio

i have been trying to end a session using the wizard to configure my bot. everytime i tested the voice calling on the bot. once it reaches the end of the conversation, it just stops and listen without ending the session, thus my Twilio Studio couldn't move on to the next step.

Comment: What's the last thing you return as a response from the bot?

Comment: Could you also maybe include screenshots of your Twilio Studio flow?